# How to display a string in a new window in Android App?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Basically I want to press a button and display a predefined string variable in a new blank window. I've tried several methods and none work. This is my first app ever so I dont have much knowledge on how to use classes. this is the code I have now for the Onclick action

```
public void receivedata(View data) {
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, ReceivedataActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("My Message", false);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and this is the code I have on the class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receivedata);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("My Message");

    TextView comm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    comm.setTextSize(40);
    comm.setText(message);

    setContentView(comm);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

The App just crashes whenever I press the button... any ideas on how to do this?

This is what the LogCat says: this is what te logcat says E/AndroidRuntime(11090): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mcudisplay/com.example.mcudisplay.ReceivedataActivity}‌​: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Comment: Always post a stack trace from logcat if you dont understand the cause of a crash.

Comment: Why are you calling `setContentView` twice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: What does log cat logs say? What is the exception?

Comment: @prijupaul this is what te logcat says E/AndroidRuntime(11090): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mcudisplay/com.example.mcudisplay.ReceivedataActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Well, the log entry seems pretty self-explanatory... :)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling setContentView twice, which suggests to me that one of these calls is wrong and unnecessary. Either `R.layout.receivedata` contains the TextView you are retrieving with `findViewById()` and you did not mean to make second call; or you DO mean to call `setContentView` with just the TextView, in which case you should inflate it separately with a LayoutInflater or create it with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

try to run your app without the line:

```
setContentView(comm);
```

You already set your content view to your receivedata.xml file.